# Superfish and hashbang

Tags: javascript, jquery, superfish, hashbang

I am considering replacing querystrings with hashbangs on my public site, for better performance.

Are menus like Superfish compatible with the hashbang? How can I trigger a content update when I click a menu item where only the hash part is different?

Comment: Before you implement hashbangs, [read this](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: Well, I'll need more serious arguments to reconsider using hashbangs...

Comment: I suggest you to use `pushState`. Much cleaner URL's, better history management. But you have to use `history.js` or something for browser compability. Regarding your question; You have to check documentation of your menu script if it's compatible with hashbang. You didn't specify which menu script you're going to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allready using jQuery on your site, i'll suggest taking a look at jQuery.address. It has a simple Interface and supports hashes and pushState. Keep in mind that you are going to have to change a lot of your serverside code when switching from querystrings to ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This plugin looks big, but I'll take a look. Actually I consume the querystrings on the client side so it's not such a big deal. My main concern is that a querystring change triggers an action (page refresh), while my page scripts won't notice a hash change.